# onclick i want to get the tr element but it gives me td element

Tags: javascript, events

I have a table and when i click on a tr element the function gives me td element. Why is that?

```
let func = function () {
    $("tr").on("click", (event)=> {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log(event.isPropagationStopped()); // true

        let targetEl = $(event.target);
        console.log(targetEl); // Object [ td ]
    });
};

func();
```

I want "onclick" to give me the tr and don't know where is the problem.
Can someone help me?

Comment: use $(this) instead

Comment: because that is what was clicked

Comment: But with arrow function "this" refers to the global window object, that's why here i use event object

Comment: [`The target property can be the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare event.target to this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when events bubble.`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Comment: @EmilianTodorov Then use a function expression instead of an arrow function.

Comment: `$(event.target).closest("tr")`

Comment: But i want to know is there a way to do this with arrow function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @epascarello now it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currentTarget or closest()

```js
$("tr").on("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('target:', event.target.tagName)
  console.log('target closest:', event.target.closest('tr').tagName)
  console.log('currentTarget:', event.currentTarget.tagName)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `event.target.closest('tr')` is the key

Answer (score 0):

This is just because you stopped the event propagation. Hence the click event wasn't transferred to the parent element. The default event propagation in JavaScript is the bubbling method. [Read this article for better understanding](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-event-propagation.php)